# Limit of $(1+\frac{1}{n^{3\alpha}})^{n^{5}}$

Tags: calculus

I was trying to solve the $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n^{3\alpha}})^{n^{5}}$
where I have to say for which $\alpha$ parameter the limit  is finite.
I tried to sobstitute $t=n^{3\alpha}$:

$(1+\frac{1}{t})^{{t}^{\frac{5}{3\alpha}}}$

and I found $\alpha \ge 0$

But the solution says  $\alpha\geq \frac{5}{3}$

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: You are right, provided this is the right statement of the question. Have you checked what the problem exactly asks?

Comment: Sorry I made some mistakes in writing the question.

Comment: That your method lead you to conclude that it would be finite for $\alpha=0$ should by itself make you suspicious: In that case, the initial limit would become $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{n^5}$ which definitely doesn't exist. (By contrast, the cases of $\alpha=1$ and $\alpha=2$ are not so obvious and so provide more interesting test cases.)

Comment: @Tarlo_x Indeed, that makes quite a difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Starting from what you did:*

First of all, for $\alpha\leq 0$ you have $1+\frac{1}{n^{3\alpha}}\geq 2$, and $2^{n^5}$ diverges to $\infty$. This settles this case, so now we consider $\alpha > 0$.

Consider what you have:

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^{{t}^{\frac{5}{3\alpha}}}
 &= \exp\left({t}^{\frac{5}{3\alpha}} \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)
 = \exp\left(\frac{{t}^{\frac{5}{3\alpha}}}{t}\cdot t \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)
\\&= \exp\left({t}^{\frac{5-3\alpha}{3\alpha}}\cdot t \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$

Recalling that $t \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)\xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{}1$, we get:

- If $5-3\alpha < 0$, then the exponent goes to $0\cdot 1=0$
- If $5-3\alpha = 0$, then the exponent goes to $1\cdot 1=1$
- If $5-3\alpha > 0$, then the exponent goes to $\infty\cdot 1=\infty$

Can you conclude?

Answer (score 2):

First exclude the case $\alpha\le0$. For $\alpha>0$, compute instead
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{3\alpha}}\right)^{x^5}
$$
(the function as opposed to the sequence). As a preparation, we compute the limit of the logarithm, but substituting $x=1/t$:
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(1+t^{3\alpha})}{t^5}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t^{3\alpha}+o(t^{3\alpha})}{t^5}
$$
and you want the limit is finite. This clearly means $3\alpha\ge 5$.

Fill in the details.

Comment: In my opinion this is by far the simplest, clearest answer. +1 Yet, wouldn't that little "o" there be better expressed as $\;\mathcal O(t^{6\alpha})\;$ = big "O"?

Comment: @Joanpemo Since the $o(t^{3\alpha})$ is enough, why go further?

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you. That's right, it is just that I've this idea that big O is better well-known and handled than little o...at least in my case.

Comment: @Joanpemo Maybe big-O is more flexible, but in the context of Taylor expansion usually little-o is sufficient.

Comment: @Joanpemo Note that here, the statement used is equivalent to $\lim_{u-\to0}\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u} = 1$, i.e. $\ln'(1)=1$. The more general statement is not that basic.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(1+\frac1{n^{3\alpha}}\right)^{n^5}=\left[\left(1+\frac1{n^{3\alpha}}\right)^{n^{3\alpha}}\right]^{n^{5-3\alpha}}$$

Now, for $\;3\alpha>0\;$ we get $\;n^{3\alpha}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\;$ , so

$$\left(1+\frac1{n^{3\alpha}}\right)^{n^{3\alpha}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e$$, and if $\;5+3\alpha>0\;$ then

$$\left[\left(1+\frac1{n^{3\alpha}}\right)^{n^{3\alpha}}\right]^{n^{5-3\alpha}}\ge 2^{n^{5-3\alpha}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$$

so we must have

$$5-3\alpha\le0\iff\alpha\ge\frac53$$